# Initialisation of for loop corrups outside its scope

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

In one of my class method declarations in which I operate with for loops and arrays, I am getting a particularly weird error. It seems like the loop initialisation of my previous loop affects the results in my next loop. Here is my code:

```
void shape::AssignTopLeftCorner()
{
     for (int i=0; i<3; i++); /this for loop affects the results...    
     int temp[4][2];
     temp[0][0]=verticies[0][0];
     temp[0][1]=verticies[0][1];    
     int topLeft;
     for(int i=1; i<4; i++)//..of this for loop
        {
                if(verticies[i][1]>temp[0][i])
                {
                  topLeft=i;
                  temp[0][0]=verticies[i][0];
                  temp[0][1]=verticies[i][1];
                }
        }
}
```

If I'd change 'i<3' to 'i<4' in the topmost loop I would get a different result, even though it is doing nothing! This problem is only computer dependant, but I have no idea what causes it. I have already done a memory test. Could it be my motherboard? OS? Any ideas?
I'm using Dev C++ 4.9.9.2

Comment: What compiler and version of it are you using?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<3; i++)` and later ... `for(int i=1; i<4; i++)`

Comment: @HanZ his loops are not nested

Comment: How is `verticies` defined? (The correct spelling is `vertices`, but that's not your problem.)

Comment: I doubt it is the first loop.   A couple of obvious problems - first you don't initialize topLeft to 0 so if that is the top left, the value is undetermined.   Second, in the if statement, you use temp[0][i] - I believe that is, at best, backward.  Likely it needs a more complex conditional based on temp[i][0] and temp[i][1].

Comment: @KeithThompson this code is only part of a method of a bigger class. Thanks for pointing out a spelling error :)

Comment: I wasn't just pointing out the spelling error. How is `verticies` defined/declared? My suspicion is that you're accessing outside the bounds of that array.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you so much! I was so blinded by this idea of the first loop affecting it that I couldn't find these basic errors!

Comment: @KeithThompson I genuinely believed that this is how you spelled it, I'm not natively english

Comment: One more time: Can you please show us the declaration of `verticies`? (I'm not talking about the misspelling; that doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that part of the problem is that you're accessing invalid elements of `temp`:

```
 int temp[4][2];
 // ...
 for(int i=1; i<4; i++)//..of this for loop
    {
            if(verticies[i][1]>temp[0][i])
```

The second dimension of `temp` has only two elements (so the only valid indices are `0` and `1`) you try to access `temp[0][1]`, `temp[0][2]`, and `temp[0][3]`.

**Edit**: In addition,

```
 for (int i=0; i<3; i++); /this for loop affects the results...
```

...is a loop with no body.  This does nothing except possibly burn a few CPU cycles, and most likely doesn't affect the code below.

Comment: It could conceivably affect the visible behavior if the code's behavior is undefined.

Comment: It was originaly part of a debugging code, but I realised that for some reason it affected my final answer. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 int temp[2];
 temp[0]=verticies[0][0];
 temp[1]=verticies[0][1];    
 int topLeft=0;
 for(int i=1; i<4; i++)//..of this for loop
    {
            if(verticies[i][1]>temp[1] && verticies[i][0]>temp[0])
            {
              topLeft=i;
              temp[0]=verticies[i][0];
              temp[1]=verticies[i][1];
            }
    }
```

Note - you may need to adjust direction of the conditionals to get top-left in your coordinate system.